# Wrong STI column is used during migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a new migration I tried to add a column and populate its values:

```
  def up
    add_column :topics, :status, :string
    Topic.reset_column_information
    Topic.find_each do |t|
      if t.ended?
        t.status = 'ended'
      end
    end
    Topic.reset_column_information
  end
```

I am not sure why, but after the column is added, during the Topic.find_each the following exception were raised:

> The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'other'.

My Topic model did have the following declared:

```
  self.inheritance_column = 'class_name'
```

So I am not sure why it still try to look up the STI subclass using the type column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that once I removed `reset_column_information`, the problem is gone.

```
    add_column :topics, :status, :string
    # Topic.reset_column_information
    Topic.find_each do |t| ...
```

`reset_column_information` probably has a bug at removing the STI column setting.